# Merge two unidentical array objects with matching same key in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two object arrays. I want to merge one array to other when fount one match like below

```
let Obj1 = [{"cols": 1, "rows": 2, "x": 0, "y": 0, SIZES: {"sizeName":"square",  "S1": "12", "S2": "14"}}, {"cols": 2, "rows": 3, "x": 1, "y": 2, SIZES: {"sizeName":"bracket",  "S1": "14", "S2": "16"}},{"cols": 4, "rows": 5, "y": 4, "x": 5, SIZES: {"sizeName":"circle",  "S1": "33", "S2": "43"}}];

let Obj2 = [["bracket","4", "2","3","2"],["square","3","2","0","2"],["circle","1","2","7","0"]]
```

Now Obj1 should compare with Obj2 `sizeName` and if matches then Obj1 will change the value of  `cols`, `rows`, `x`, `y` with Obj2 `cols`, `rows`, `x`, `y` value as below

```
let expected = let x = [{"cols": 3, "rows": 2, "x": 0, "y": 2, SIZES: {"sizeName":"square",  "S1": "12", "S2": "14"}}, {"cols": 4, "rows": 2, "x": 3, "y": 2, SIZES: {"sizeName":"bracket",  "S1": "14", "S2": "16"}},{"cols": 1, "rows": 2, "y": 7, "x": 0, SIZES: {"sizeName":"circle",  "S1": "33", "S2": "43"}}];
```

Can you please help me to create the expected array structure? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple and savage way, easy to understand

```js
const expected = Obj1.map((i) => {
  const temp = Obj2.find((j) => j[0] === i.SIZES['sizeName']);
  return temp
    ? { ...i, cols: temp[1], rows: temp[2], x: temp[3], y: temp[4] }
    : i;
});
```

Comment: You can do the trick by using destructuring array like this `const [, cols, rows, x, y] = temp;`

Answer (score 1):

You can complete by iterating `Obj1`, then `Array#find` from `Obj2` like this.

```js
let Obj1=[{"cols":1,"rows":2,"x":0,"y":0,SIZES:{"sizeName":"square","S1":"12","S2":"14"}},{"cols":2,"rows":3,"x":1,"y":2,SIZES:{"sizeName":"bracket","S1":"14","S2":"16"}},{"cols":4,"rows":5,"y":4,"x":5,SIZES:{"sizeName":"circle","S1":"33","S2":"43"}}];
let Obj2=[["bracket","4","2","3","2"],["square","3","2","0","2"],["circle","1","2","7","0"]];

const result = Obj1.map(item => {
  const foundItem2 = Obj2.find(r => r[0] === item.SIZES.sizeName);
  if(!foundItem2) return item;

  const [, cols, rows, x, y] = foundItem2;
  return {...item, cols, rows, x, y};
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @zixiCat and Nguyễn Văn Phong both are giving correct answer. Thank you very much. Thanks for your effort.